# DHCP - General relativity

Tags: dhcp

The following image shows a visualization of the DHCP server in action. DHCP servers send a **DHCPNACK** message in a scenario where the same ip address is trying to be assigned to 2 devices. Is this basically based on general relativity, like an equation where we take the DHCP server as the reference point?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about general relativity, but yes, the DHCP server is the "source of truth".

When a client reconnects to a network it was previously attached to, it may include the Requested IP Address field, offering a hint to the server that it would prefer it's old IP address back, however it may no longer be available (either due to the server leasing it back out to another client, or a client with a static IP address occupying the address) and a NACK will be sent.